# How to create a dynamic menu in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The idea is to dynamically create a menu structure with submenus and then expose it in a REST API so frontend can print the menu.

Each menu point can have multiple submenu and each submenu can have multiple submenu inside, like:

```
- Menu 1
  - Submenu 1.1
    - Submenu 1.1.1
    - Submenu 1.1.2
  - Submenu 1.2
    - Submenu 1.2.1
    - Submenu 1.2.2
- Menu 2
  - [...]
```

What should be the structure of the models and serializers to fulfill the described function?

I tried to do it with a single model like:

```
class MenuPoint(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  [...]
  parent_menu_point = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='submenu_point',
        blank=True,
        null=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use [django-treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/) or [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/) for tree-like models.

Comment: Looks like Tree and recursive query is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use nested one to many field relations. Something like:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
...


class SubMenu(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  parent_menu = models.ForeignKey(
        'Menu',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='submenu',
        blank=True,
        null=True)
...


class SubSubMenu(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  parent_menu = models.ForeignKey(
        'SubMenu',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='subsubmenu',
        blank=True,
        null=True)
...
```

Please do any corrections required as i am also a newbie in Django. I just provided an idea how it would work.